# Fooman GA+ double ga.js inclusion (so it seems)

Tags: google-analytics

Whilst investigating site speed I saw that the header contains the google analytics code twice (as in double).

We have googleanalytics.xml (default) and googleanalyticsplus.xml installed

The double code looks like this (Image exact two copies directly under each other)

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
(function(){var ga=document.createElement('script');ga.type='text/javascript';ga.async=true;ga.src='https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);})();var _gaq=_gaq||[];_gaq.push(["_setAccount","UA-CODEHERE"]);asyncDistilledFirstTouch(_gaq);_gaq.push(["_trackPageview",""],["_trackPageLoadTime"]);if(Ajax.Responders){Ajax.Responders.register({onComplete:function(response){if(!response.url.include("progress")&&!response.url.include("getAdditional")){if(response.url.include("saveOrder")){_gaq.push(["_trackPageview",""+"/opc-review-placeOrderClicked"]);}else if(accordion.currentSection){_gaq.push(["_trackPageview","/"+accordion.currentSection]);}}}});}
//]]></script>
```

Generated (I think) by

googleanalytics.xml

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
    <reference name="head" before="-">
        <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

and

googleanalyticsplus.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs" ifconfig="google/analyticsplus/firstouch"><script>GoogleAnalyticsPlus/distilled.FirstTouch.js</script></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="before_head_end" as="before_head_end"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="before_head_end">
        <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>google_analytics</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>google_analytics</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="googleanalyticsplus/gaConversion" name="googleanalyticsplus_conversion" template="googleanalyticsplus/ga-conversion.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
<checkout_multishipping_success>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="googleanalyticsplus/gaConversion" name="googleanalyticsplus_conversion" template="googleanalyticsplus/ga-conversion.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_multishipping_success>
```

Comment: And if you disable core GA?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed adding

```
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>google_analytics</name></action>
    </reference>
```

to googleanalyticsplus.xml

strange that it unsets a lot of header before and after, but not the main head where the original code is posted